# MySQL text field issues

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is quite a noobish question, I have searched for a few hours now and I know this has to be simple. I am using XAMPP and I am trying to learn some more about using PHP and mySQL together. When I create the DB and the table for information to store, I tried insert info to the table and it stores it as a .dat file rather than text. I know this has to be with how I am setting up the table or the DB but I have gone through things and I think I am just skipping over something.

```
* Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
* MySQL client version: 5.1.37
* PHP extension: mysqli
```

that is the phpmyadmin info.

Comment: Please be more specific.
What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry.

Ok so I am creating a simple user login. I have created a DB and then a table for the user info. All the statements work fine no errors. When I ran it, I went and check the DB and it says "binary_file.dat" in place of where the text is supposed to be. I figure it is something stupid and small just not sure.

Comment: I see nobody understood your question, but it really is confusing a bit. :) See my answer for a solution.

Comment: Ya I learned two things today. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're editing table field's properties, there is one which affect presentation of the field data in phpMyAdmin: "Browser transformation". When it is set to "application/octetstream: download" for some field, phpMyAdmin instead of displaying text "as is", allows to download its content as a (binary) file and displays that as a "binary_file.dat" url to that file.

You can change this behavior by changing "Browser transformation" for your text field to something else (an empty value would be good).

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Of the options for that which is the best for any text? I just left it with text/plain: formatted

Comment: @chenger, you can read tooltips for each option in the list, there are explanations what each transformation does. "text/plain: formatted" is good if your field contains valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that when you do something like

```
SELECT textfield FROM datatable;
```

on your database, you get a result that looks like:

```
+-----------------+
|    textfield    |
+-----------------+
| binary_file.dat |
+-----------------+
```

instead of getting the contents of the file you'd tried to insert?